# Recursive Function to get all files from main folder and subdirectories inside it in Python

Tags: python, pandas, operating-system

I have a file directory that looks something like this. I have a larger directory, but showing this one just for explanation purposes:

```
.
├── a.txt
├── b.txt
├── foo
│   └── w.txt
│   └── a.txt
└── moo
    └── cool.csv
    └── bad.csv
    └── more
        └── wow.csv
```

I want to write a recursive function to get year counts for files within each subdirectory within this directory.

I want the code to basically check if it's a directory or file. If it's a directory then I want to call the function again and get counts until there's no more subdirectories.

I have the following code (which keeps breaking my kernel when I test it). There's probably some logic error as well I would think..

```
import os
import pandas as pd

dir_path = 'S:\\Test'

def getFiles(dir_path):
     contents = os.listdir(dir_path)
     # check if content is directory or not
     for file in contents:
          if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(dir_path, file)):
               # get everything inside subdirectory
               getFiles(dir_path = os.path.join(dir_path, file))
          # it's a file
          else:
               # do something to get the year of the file and put it in a list or something
     # at the end create pandas data frame and return
```

Expected output would be a pandas dataframe that looks something like this..

```
Subdir 2020 2021 2022
foo    0    1    1
moo    0    2    0
more   1    0    0
```

How can I do this in Python?

**EDIT:**

Just realized os.walk() is probably extremely useful for my case here.

Trying to figure out a solution with os.walk() instead of doing it the long way..

Comment: Look into `os.walk`.

Comment: Another option would be `pathlib.rglob` to get all the files and then parse/group the file paths to get your counts

Comment: os.walk() looks promising...trying to figure it out right now using os.walk().